# router.navigate not working and allows statements below it to execute

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-routing, angular-router

I am calling 2 methods in the `ngOnInit`: one method checks for **path parameters** and the other one looks for **query parameters** in the url.

Here's the `ngOnInit` method:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getFlavorAndService();
  this.getQueryParams();
}
```

Here's the method that looks for **path params**:

```
getFlavorAndService(): void {
    this.routePathParamsSubscription = this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
      const flavor: string = params.flavor;
      const service: string = params.service;

      if (flavor) {
        if (this._dataService.flavors.includes(flavor)) {
          this.flavor = flavor;
        } else {
          this._router.navigate(['/page-not-found']);
        }
      } else {
        this._router.navigate(['', this._dataService.DEFAULT_FLAVOR, this._dataService.DEFAULT_SERVICE]);
      }

      if (service) {
        if (this._dataService.isEdsService(service)) {
          this.service = service;
        } else {
          this._router.navigate(['/page-not-found']);
        }
      } else {
        this._router.navigate(['', this._dataService.DEFAULT_FLAVOR, this._dataService.DEFAULT_SERVICE]);
      }
    });
  }
```

Here's the method that looks for **query params**:

```
getQueryParams(): void {
  this.routeQueryParamsSubscription = this._route.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
    ..... some code

    if (isEmpty(queryParams)) {
      this._router.navigate(['', this._dataService.flavor, this.service]);
    } else {
      this._router.navigate(['', this._dataService.flavor, this.service], { queryParams: queryParams, queryParamsHandling: 'merge' });
    }
  });
}
```

My question is that, if an invalid flavor is passed I should be redirected to `/page-not-found` url and the remaining statements should not executed at all. Instead, when I pass invalid flavor or service, the webapp doesn't navigate to **page-not-found** url, and the remaining statements of the method get executed (from getQueryParams methods). It doesn't redirect,even if I use `return this._router.navigate(['/page-not-found']);`.

Should the app not get navigated to `page-not-found` and stop?

Comment: *and the remaining statements should not executed at all*: why would that happen? You don't return, and router.navigate() doesn't throw any exception. So the remaining statements are executed, as per the rules of TypeScript/JavaScript.

Comment: Just need clarification that what this code implies . this._router.navigate(['', this._dataService.DEFAULT_FLAVOR, this._dataService.DEFAULT_SERVICE]);

Comment: @JBNizet, the app is not navigating to page-not-found at all. I tried to put console.log in ngOnInit in the component associated with page-not-found route, but that was not called at all. Also, can I use return router.navigate instead of just router.navigate?

Comment: @Manpreet this._router.navigate(['', this._dataService.DEFAULT_FLAVOR, this._dataService.DEFAULT_SERVICE]) will navigate the webapp to the default routes that I have specified in the app. I have dynamic routes in the app.

Comment: You can, but that doesn't make much sense. Why would you want to return the promise returned by rouer.navigate()? Why not just use `return;` after the call to router.navigate()?

Comment: @PritamBohra so the mentioned dependencies are correct ?

Comment: @PritamBohra can you debug that control goes in else condition or not, either by logging in console.

Comment: @JBNizet, your comments make complete sense to me now. But, I still didn't understand why it's not redirecting to page-not-found component at all?

Comment: @JBNizet, I got the answer why page-not-found gets called at all. I tried with this:
    this.router.navigate(['flavor']);
    this.router.navigate(['page-not-found']);
    this.router.navigate(['service']);
and the last navigate (service) overrides the other 2. It won't even call the components associated with flavor and page-not-found routes.

Answer (score -1):

just to make sure constructor function should be as

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}
```

and use return `this._router.navigate(['/page-not-found'`])